# QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin" (file not found) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video

I'm running YouTube video by providing the YouTube url to webview which opens the YouTube video and runs it in MPMoviePlayerController on click automatically.

It works well on simulator but on device it gives me following warning:

> warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.2/Symbols/System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin" (file not found).

But video keeps running in the background as I am able to hear the sound.

How to deal with this error?

Comment: I think you might be missing a framework that's only being used while in the simulator but required when run on the device.

Comment: Are you using unpublished API calls?

Comment: See the answer on this one, it's the same issue actually, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942981/youtube-integration-warning/8943222#8943222

Answer (score 1):

Look out for your bse sdk versions of ios device and version on which you running code in simlutor..as Fulvio mentioned it must be mismatch of sdk versions where your device may not have particuler framework