# Youtube integration - Warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, youtube-api

I got this warning when i ran the application on my iPhone.

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/illep/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J3)/Symbols/System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/YouTubePlugIn.webplugin/YouTubePlugIn (file not found).

warning: No copy of YouTubePlugIn.webplugin/YouTubePlugIn found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

What does it mean ? and how can i get rid of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That simply means that YouTubePlugIn doesn't exist in you Mac for XCode to use, so the plugin will need to be loaded from device. You can safely ignore the warning, this will happen when you're debugging. (Won't happen in deployed app)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this plugin in the simulator. You'll need to test it on a real device. The Simulator doesn't have the YouTube app.

Comment: No, this warning occurred when testing it on the device

Comment: I see. I can't find the plugin in my 4.3 folder(s). It is in 4.2 and 5.0 though. As it is a warning you can ignore it.  It only affects debugging (as it states)